# Childview doesn't appear in parent view

Tags: ios

I try to build controller with 3 child view, that can be switched by segmented control. Problem is that instead of content of 2 of 3 controllers I see white screen.

Code is the following

```
@IBAction func segmentedControllSelected(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:

        self.parentView.addSubview(subViewOne!)
        subViewOne?.frame = subViewOne!.superview!.bounds
        subViewOne?.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]

        subViewTwo?.removeFromSuperview()
        subViewThree?.removeFromSuperview()
    case 1:

        self.parentView.addSubview(subViewTwo!)
        subViewTwo?.frame = subViewTwo!.superview!.bounds
        subViewTwo?.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]

        subViewOne?.removeFromSuperview()
        subViewThree?.removeFromSuperview()
    case 2:

        self.parentView.addSubview(subViewThree!)
        subViewThree?.frame = subViewThree!.superview!.bounds
        subViewThree?.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        print("parentView frame is \(parentView.frame.height)")
        print("scrollView contentSize is \(scrollView.contentSize.height)")
        print("subViewThree frame is \(subViewThree?.frame.height)")
        subViewThree?.frame.size.height = 2000
        print("subViewThree frame is \(subViewThree?.frame.height)")

        subViewOne?.removeFromSuperview()
        subViewTwo?.removeFromSuperview()

    default:
        break;
    }

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    segmentedControllPositionY = segmentedControll.frame.origin.y
    scrollView.delegate = self

    gameInfoMainViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "GameInfo", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameInfoMainViewController") as? GameInfoMainViewController
    gameInfoMembersViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "GameInfo", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameInfoMembersViewController") as? GameInfoMembersViewController
    gameInfoTeamsViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "GameInfo", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameInfoTeamsViewController") as? GameInfoTeamsViewController
    gameInfoTeamsViewController!.delegate = self

    self.addChildViewController(gameInfoMainViewController!)
    self.addChildViewController(gameInfoMembersViewController!)
    self.addChildViewController(gameInfoTeamsViewController!)

    subViewOne = gameInfoMainViewController!.view
    subViewTwo = gameInfoMembersViewController!.view
    subViewThree = gameInfoTeamsViewController!.view

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.parentView.addSubview(subViewOne!)
    subViewOne!.frame = subViewOne!.superview!.bounds

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > segmentedControllPositionY! - 40 {
        segmentedControllTopConstraint.constant = scrollView.contentOffset.y + 40
    } else {
        segmentedControllTopConstraint.constant = segmentedControllPositionY!

    }

}

func passHeight(height:CGFloat) { // delegate method which is called in controller with tableview and passes height of tableview
    tableViewHeight = height
    parentView.frame.size.height = tableViewHeight!
    parentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    scrollView.contentSize.height = tableViewHeight! + segmentedControll!.frame.height + headerView.frame.size.height
}
```

here is how child view controller looks

[image]

here is how it looks in simulator (white screen, no label)

[image]

If I remove

```
subViewTwo?.frame = subViewTwo!.superview!.bounds
subViewTwo?.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
```

I end up with this

[image]

Comment: What is parentView? Is it correctly placed on screen? Why don't you use child view controllers? https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Adding-and-Removing-Child-View-Controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this provide some help,I think it is easier to use a container view & fill it with your switchable views, this will be done by setting activeViewController which will remove inactive view & show the other view filling containerView frame

```
        gameInfoMainViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "GameInfo", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameInfoMainViewController") as? GameInfoMainViewController
        gameInfoMembersViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "GameInfo", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameInfoMembersViewController") as? GameInfoMembersViewController
        gameInfoTeamsViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "GameInfo", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameInfoTeamsViewController") as? GameInfoTeamsViewController
        gameInfoTeamsViewController!.delegate = self

// to be called in view didAppear
activeViewController = gameInfoMainViewController    


       private var activeViewController: UIViewController? {
            didSet {
                removeInactiveViewController(oldValue)
                updateActiveViewController()
            }
        }

        private func removeInactiveViewController(inactiveViewController: UIViewController?) {
            if let inActiveVC = inactiveViewController {
                inActiveVC.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)

                inActiveVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
                inActiveVC.removeFromParentViewController()
            }
        }

        private func updateActiveViewController() {
            if let activeVC = activeViewController {
                addChildViewController(activeVC)

                activeVC.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
                activeVC.view.autoresizingMask = [ UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight , UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth]

                activeVC.view.frame = contentView.bounds
                contentView.addSubview(activeVC.view)
                // contentView is the containerView
                activeVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
            }
        }
```

And here is the UI to use When user select an item from segment view you should change active view to load another view
[image]

Comment: Just great! Thanks a lot!